# How does nginx forward a header with a $ sign

Tags: http, nginx

A Http Request has a header : **$name**,access nginx forward ,the header will lose ,but I need the header:$name,how can I config the nginx?

example:

```
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   $name $http_$name;
    }
```

Comment: GET /api/get1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
$model: xxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

Escape dollar sign by creating a variable with it:

```
http {
    geo $dollar {
        default "$";
    }
    server {
        ...
        location /api/ { 
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/; 
            proxy_redirect off; 
            proxy_set_header Host $host; 
            proxy_set_header ${dollar}name $http_$name; 
        }
    }
}
```